# Solving complex numbers with omega

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\omega^2+\omega+1=0$$
This is the only rule I know about this lesson and of course its other forms, and i just can't figure out how to reach a number as answer for this, I tried using the other forms like $\omega^2+\omega=-1$ but it gets me nowhere.

$$\left({1\over 1+i\omega}-{i+\omega\over 1+\omega^{2i}}\right)^8$$

Comment: Hint: $w^2+w+1=0\implies w^3-1=(w-1)(w^2+w+1)=0$

Answer (score 3):

The "smart" solution here is to note that (if $\omega\ne1$) the LHS is a geometric series and we have that

$$\omega^2+\omega+1 = {\omega^3-1\over\omega-1}$$.

Since $\omega=1$ is no solution this boils down to the equation

$$\omega^3 = 1$$

with the solutions $\omega = e^{2in\pi/3}$ (where we must omit the solution $\omega=1$).

The no-brainer is to complete the square (or use quadratic formula):

$$\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = \left(\omega+{1\over2}\right)^2-{1\over4} + 1$$

Then the equation boils down to:

$$\left(\omega+{1\over2}\right)^2 =  -{3\over 4}$$

which have the solutions

$$\omega = -{1\over2}\pm i{\sqrt{3}\over2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the quadratic formula:

$$\omega^2+\omega+1=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot1\cdot1}}{2\cdot1}=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag1$$

Answer (score 0):

$(a+bw+cw^2)^3+(a+bw^2+cw)^3=27abc$

Comment: Plz solved me the problem